# loop input field into every table column using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add the input field into every table column just like the picture below. Can any of you give me some suggestion on how do I loop through into the input field to every table column?
Every single help would be appreciated!
Below is my code snippet, any answer is greatly appreciated!!! Thank you for all the help!

[image]

```js
function displayCalendar(){


    var htmlContent ="";
    var FebNumberOfDays ="";
    var counter = 1;
    var calCon = "";


    var dateNow = new Date();
    var month = dateNow.getMonth();

    var nextMonth = month+1;
    var prevMonth = month -1;
    var day = dateNow.getDate();
    var year = dateNow.getFullYear();


    if (month == 1){
    if ( (year%100!=0) && (year%4==0) || (year%400==0)){
    FebNumberOfDays = 29;
    }else{
    FebNumberOfDays = 28;
    }
    }


    var monthNames = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November", "December"];
    var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thrusday","Friday", "Saturday"];
    var dayPerMonth = ["31", ""+FebNumberOfDays+"","31","30","31","30","31","31","30","31","30","31"]


    var nextDate = new Date(nextMonth +' 1 ,'+year);
    var weekdays= nextDate.getDay();
    var weekdays2 = weekdays
    var numOfDays = dayPerMonth[month];



    while (weekdays>0){
    htmlContent += "<td class='monthPre'></td>";


    weekdays--;
    }


    while (counter <= numOfDays){


    if (weekdays2 > 6){
    weekdays2 = 0;
    htmlContent += "</tr><tr>";
    }


    if (counter == day){
    htmlContent +="<td class='dayNow'  onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"' "+
    "onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"; this.style.color=\"#00FF00\"'>"+counter+"</td>";
    }else{
    htmlContent +="<td class='monthNow' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"'"+
    " onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'>"+counter+"</td>";    

    }

    weekdays2++;
    counter++;
    }



    // This Code Doesn't Work
    var calCon = "<div id='hide'>"
    +monthNames[month]+" "+ year +"";
    calCon +="<label>";
    calCon += "<input id='files' type='file' />";
    calCon += "<span class='fa fa-plus'></span>";
    calCon += "</label>";
    calCon += "<output class='img-responsive' id='result'/>";
    calCon += calCon;
    calCon += "</div>";

    document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML=calCon;


    var calendarBody = "<table class='calendar'> <tr class='monthNow'>"
    +monthNames[month]+" "+ year +"</tr>";
    calendarBody +="<tr class='dayNames'><td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tues</td>"+
    "<td>Wed</td><td>Thurs</td><td>Fri</td> <td>Sat</td> </tr>";
    calendarBody += "<tr>";
    calendarBody += htmlContent;
    calendarBody += "</tr></table>";

    document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML=calendarBody;


    }
```

```css
  .monthPre{
    color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    }


    td.monthNow {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1pxx solid black;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    }


    .dayNow{
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: #FF0000;
    text-align: center;
    }


    .calendar{
    width: 100%;
    }


    .monthNow th{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;

    }


    .dayNames {
    background: yellow;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head> 
    <title>JavaScript calendar</title>

    </head> 

    <body onload="displayCalendar()"> 

    <div id="calendar"></div> 

    </body> 

    </html>
```

Comment: every columns or every cells?

Comment: @axelaxel Hmm, just like the picture above. Sorry if I'm messing up with the columns or cell

Comment: I can't see a loop for your input field? Or did you wanted to get one right? Anyhow you shouldn't use the same ID for every input field. Also you are setting the inner html of calculator twice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to move this block:

```
calCon = "<div id='hide'>" +
  monthNames[month] + " " + year + "";
calCon += "<label>";
calCon += "<input id='files' type='file' />";
calCon += "<span class='fa fa-plus'></span>";
calCon += "</label>";
calCon += calCon;
calCon += "<output class='img-responsive' id='result'/>";
```

inside the while-loop and get rid of this line:

```
calCon += calCon;
```

Afterwards simply update the **htmlContent** variable with **calCon**

```
if (counter == day) {
  htmlContent += "<td class='dayNow'  onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"' " +
    "onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"; this.style.color=\"#00FF00\"'>" + counter + "</td>";
} else {
  htmlContent += "<td class='monthNow' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"'" +
    " onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'>" + calCon + counter + "</td>";
}
```

Here's the complete example:

```js
function displayCalendar() {


  var htmlContent = "";
  var FebNumberOfDays = "";
  var counter = 1;
  var calCon = "";


  var dateNow = new Date();
  var month = dateNow.getMonth();

  var nextMonth = month + 1;
  var prevMonth = month - 1;
  var day = dateNow.getDate();
  var year = dateNow.getFullYear();


  if (month == 1) {
    if ((year % 100 != 0) && (year % 4 == 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
      FebNumberOfDays = 29;
    } else {
      FebNumberOfDays = 28;
    }
  }


  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thrusday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  var dayPerMonth = ["31", "" + FebNumberOfDays + "", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31"]


  var nextDate = new Date(nextMonth + ' 1 ,' + year);
  var weekdays = nextDate.getDay();
  var weekdays2 = weekdays
  var numOfDays = dayPerMonth[month];



  while (weekdays > 0) {
    htmlContent += "<td class='monthPre'></td>";


    weekdays--;
  }


  while (counter <= numOfDays) {


    if (weekdays2 > 6) {
      weekdays2 = 0;
      htmlContent += "</tr><tr>";
    }
    calCon = "<div id='hide'>" +
      monthNames[month] + " " + year + "";
    calCon += "<label>";
    calCon += "<input id='files' type='file' />";
    calCon += "<span class='fa fa-plus'></span>";
    calCon += "</label>";
    calCon += "<output class='img-responsive' id='result'/>";

    calCon += "</div>";
    if (counter == day) {
      htmlContent += "<td class='dayNow'  onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"' " +
        "onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"; this.style.color=\"#00FF00\"'>" + counter + "</td>";
    } else {
      htmlContent += "<td class='monthNow' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"'" +
        " onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'>" + calCon + counter + "</td>";
    }

    weekdays2++;
    counter++;
  }



  // This Code Doesn't Work





  var calendarBody = "<table class='calendar'> <tr class='monthNow'>" +
    monthNames[month] + " " + year + "</tr>";
  calendarBody += "<tr class='dayNames'><td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tues</td>" +
    "<td>Wed</td><td>Thurs</td><td>Fri</td> <td>Sat</td> </tr>";
  calendarBody += "<tr>";
  calendarBody += htmlContent;
  calendarBody += "</tr></table>";

  document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = calendarBody;


}
```

```css
.monthPre {
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

td.monthNow {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1pxx solid black;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.dayNow {
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: #FF0000;
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar {
  width: 100%;
}

.monthNow th {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.dayNames {
  background: yellow;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="displayCalendar()">
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `<input type='file'/>` in your htmlContent of javascript

```js
function displayCalendar(){


    var htmlContent ="";
    var FebNumberOfDays ="";
    var counter = 1;
    var calCon = "";


    var dateNow = new Date();
    var month = dateNow.getMonth();

    var nextMonth = month+1;
    var prevMonth = month -1;
    var day = dateNow.getDate();
    var year = dateNow.getFullYear();


    if (month == 1){
    if ( (year%100!=0) && (year%4==0) || (year%400==0)){
    FebNumberOfDays = 29;
    }else{
    FebNumberOfDays = 28;
    }
    }


    var monthNames = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November", "December"];
    var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thrusday","Friday", "Saturday"];
    var dayPerMonth = ["31", ""+FebNumberOfDays+"","31","30","31","30","31","31","30","31","30","31"]


    var nextDate = new Date(nextMonth +' 1 ,'+year);
    var weekdays= nextDate.getDay();
    var weekdays2 = weekdays
    var numOfDays = dayPerMonth[month];



    while (weekdays>0){
    htmlContent += "<td class='monthPre'></td>";


    weekdays--;
    }


    while (counter <= numOfDays){


    if (weekdays2 > 6){
    weekdays2 = 0;
    htmlContent += "</tr><tr>";
    }


    if (counter == day){
    htmlContent +="<td class='dayNow'  onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"' "+
    "onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"; this.style.color=\"#00FF00\"'><input id='fileupload"+counter+"' type='file' />"+counter+"</td>";
    }else{
    htmlContent +="<td class='monthNow' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"'"+
    " onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'><input id='fileupload"+counter+"' type='file' />"+counter+"</td>";    

    }

    weekdays2++;
    counter++;
    }



    // This Code Doesn't Work
    var calCon = "<div id='hide'>"
    +monthNames[month]+" "+ year +"";
    calCon +="<label>";
    calCon += "<input id='files' type='file' />";
    calCon += "<span class='fa fa-plus'></span>";
    calCon += "</label>";
    calCon += "<output class='img-responsive' id='result'/>";
    calCon += calCon;
    calCon += "</div>";

    document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML=calCon;


    var calendarBody = "<table class='calendar'> <tr class='monthNow'>"
    +monthNames[month]+" "+ year +"</tr>";
    calendarBody +="<tr class='dayNames'><td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tues</td>"+
    "<td>Wed</td><td>Thurs</td><td>Fri</td> <td>Sat</td> </tr>";
    calendarBody += "<tr>";
    calendarBody += htmlContent;
    calendarBody += "</tr></table>";

    document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML=calendarBody;


    }
```

```css
.monthPre{
    color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    }


    td.monthNow {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1pxx solid black;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    }


    .dayNow{
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: #FF0000;
    text-align: center;
    }


    .calendar{
    width: 100%;
    }


    .monthNow th{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;

    }


    .dayNames {
    background: yellow;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head> 
    <title>JavaScript calendar</title>

    </head> 

    <body onload="displayCalendar()"> 

    <div id="calendar"></div> 

    </body> 

    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer here, it really helped me to understand more!